# In Google Maps, I am unable to remove a saved place (single location) within a saved private list

Tags: google-maps

In Google Maps, I have created a list that has individual saved places (points) in it.  I'm having trouble successfully removing places from this list even though I follow the correct procedures.

For completeness in explaining the problem, here is how I save places to this list: I establish a dropped pin on the map and then click the 'Save' icon on the menu which gives me a listing of my lists, then I click on the list I want to save it to, and it then properly saves to the list and places a blue pin marker for it.  This works fine... BUT when I want to REMOVE some of the places on this list that I've put on this way, I'm unable to do that.

This is the procedure I follow to remove them, as recommended by Google Maps:
I click the menu drop-down at top left, go to "Your Places", then I select the desired list, it displays the places, then I click the menu drop-down at the top (3 dots), select "Edit List", and I then click on the X's next to each place I want to remove. As I click the X next to each one, the places do get removed from the list and below on the list, it says changes are being auto-saved. So it appears to be operating correctly... BUT the points do not then disappear from the map, and when I close the editing bar, the points still do not disappear from the map, and when I reopen the list again, the places I deleted have returned to the list.  I cannot successfully remove them.

I believe there's a bug here as I've assured I'm following the proper procedures and have reproduced the problem repeatedly and consistently.

Other possibly important notes:

1. I have placed these dropped pins on the map by putting a latitude, longitude point in the 'Search Google Maps' window where you type in a place.  This does properly place a pin on the map, which I then save successfully to a list as I described above.
2. It may also be important to note that I'm doing this on a PC, not a mobile device.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because troubleshooting like questions are off-topic in Web Applications SE.